# Which Directed Electronics Module is This?

Tags: electronics, alarm, aftermarket-upgrade

Isn’t water a wonderful thing?  My '76 Corvette had a water leak in the windshield and the rain obliterated a module that was installed under the dash.  I bought and installed it around 2012 or 2013.  There are no definitive markings on the case or on the PCB, so I don’t know what module I need to replace it with.  I’ve searched online to no avail.  I just can't seem to find one of their modules that look exactly like this.  I've even emailed Directed Electronics directly about this, but of course, no reply from them.

The rain messed with more than one module (which has made more than one thing quit working), so without tracing everything down, I can't easily identify what this module is for.  So yes, I'm being lazy, but hopefully there's an alarm system guy on here that can easily recognize this to save me the trouble of tearing everything apart.  I do know I've added a few modules for different things, but I just don't recognize what this module is for.  I've added remote power windows, power door locks, proximity sensor, etc.  They work in conjunction with a Python security system (unfortunately, I don't know the model of the Python).  The wiring is all there and in good shape.  I'm just hoping someone recognizes exactly which module this is, so I can find a plug and play, direct replacement.  Thanks.

[image: PCB Bottom]

[image: PCB Top]

[image: Case Top]

[image: Case Bottom]

Comment: Appears to be a power window module since there are 2 relays, just an educated guess.

Comment: Appreciate it.  I've looked at 529T, 530T and 535T modules.  Not sure if that's all that they offer, but those are the only modules I can find for windows.  None of them match.  Either more pins on the single plug, or more than one plug.  This is kind of a pain in the rectum.

Comment: A good reason to document install of new electronics.

Comment: @Moab  Yeah, yeah, smart aleck...  :)  Hindsight is 20/20.  Mark my words though, the future will tell a different story.

Comment: not being a smart alek, just good advice for the future.

Comment: I know it.  Just having a little fun.  And yes, it certainly is good advice.  I actually feel pretty ridiculous for not documenting like I should have.